# What is the best way to check if a directory and its content is locked?

Tags: java, locking

Suppose I pass a string containing the path to a directory to a random method. Before this method starts working it should check if the directory or any of its content is locked. I thought this would be a simple task, but turned out I got some hardly simple code to do it. Do you have any suggestions how to improve it or at least make it shorter?

If you think that is already the best solution just give it an up vote and go on solving real problems :P

```
public static boolean checkLocks(String path) {

    File f = new File(path);

    if(f.isDirectory()) {
        boolean ans = true;;
        String files[] = f.list();

        for (String file : files) {
            File ff = new File(f, file);
            ans = checkLocks(ff.toString());
            if(!ans){
                break;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    } else {
        try {
            RandomAccessFile stream = new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw");
            FileChannel channel = stream.getChannel();

            FileLock lock = null;
            try {
                lock = channel.tryLock();
            } catch (final OverlappingFileLockException e) {
                stream.close();
                channel.close();
                System.out.println("File at "+path+" locked");
                return false;
            }
            stream.close();
            channel.close();
            return true;

        } catch (IOException eio) {
            System.out.println("File at "+path+" does not exits");
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking each file in the directory strikes me as slow and prone to race conditions.  In your example you're getting a list of files in the directory at an instant and then you test each; meanwhile the creator thread may still be adding files.  Even if every file in your list is accessible, the creator may not be finished writing the directory.

It's somewhat old-school and not very fancy but I would use either a temporary directory name while creation is in progress or write a lockfile as the first file and delete it when the creator is finished.

In the first case:

```
String baseDirectory = "{whatever}";
String workDirectory = "workDirectory" + counter;
Path tempPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(baseDirectory, ".temp_" + workDirectory);
Path workPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(baseDirectory, workDirectory);
Files.createDirectory(tempPath);
// Write the contents of the directory.
// [...]
Files.move(tempPath, workPath, CopyOptions.ATOMIC_MOVE);
```

In the second case:

```
String baseDirectory = "{whatever}";
String workDirectory = "workDirectory" + counter;
Path workPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(baseDirectory, workDirectory);
Files.createDirectory(workPath);
Path lockFile = workPath.resolve("LOCKFILE");
Files.createFile(lockFile);
// Write the contents of the directory.
// [...]
Files.delete(lockFile);
```

The idea in both cases is that the creator task explicitly signals when it's done creating the directory.  If you just wait for a pause in operations, it could just be waiting for a large buffer to load over the network.

Comment: Do I assume right, that the worker threads are supposed to look for the File called LOCKFILE and if it exits they know the job is locked? And what is the counter variable supposed to to? just a name separation from the working directories of the different creators?

Comment: Yes, the workers look for "LOCKFILE" to check if the creator is still running in that directory.  And yes, the counter was just a way to write a code sketch so that the temp directories wouldn't accidentally conflict; you'll probably have a more robust pattern for unique naming in real life.

Comment: Alright I already implemented your solution. It works very good. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use the `Files` class and its `is*` methods like `isReadable` and `isWritable`.

```
if (Files.isReadable(new File(filepath).toPath()) &&
    Files.isWritable(new File(filepath).toPath()))
{
    /* do something... */
}
```

Should work for regular files and folders.

Comment: Hey good idea. But it returns always returns false, even when the other process is finished. I think thats because a zip file never qualifies as writable and the folder I am checking contains zip files.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood your original question. I guess there's no convenience method then. I'm curious what the use case is. Because the `tryLock` method just checks for locks that are held by the same VM as far as I understand it. I suppose this feature is very platform dependent.

Comment: The use case is a job queue. There is a creator thread which copies jobs in form of directories into a queue directory. Now the worker threads are looking into the queue and are taking jobs to work on. But before that they have to check if the job directory is locked. It would crash if the creator is not finished copying all the files

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use  SimpleFileVistor class instead of writing a code to walk through directory.

There is already built in method in Files class to walk through the directory.

```
Files.walkFileTree(path, MyFileVisitor)
```

You can create a customer visitor class like

```
public class MyFileVisitor  extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>{


    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Visit  the File")
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("File Visit Failed")
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

This can improve your code readability and it is less verbose.